# Not able to read numbers in word documents using python?

Tags: python, ms-word, spacy

I am reading .Docx documents using packages like docx2txt, docx2python & docx in python. However, I am not able to read numbers under a specific section and the word document has numbers.

[Some paragraphs before Questions]

Questions:

1. Question1?
2. Question2? another question?
3. Question3?

Conclusions:

1. Text related to question1.
2. Text related to question2.
3. Text related to question3.

I need to identify number of questions under questions section and it should match this number with the number of conclusions. In this case,  it is 3 questions and 3 conclusions.

For instance:
[[['',
'Executive Summary',
'Context',
'LIBOR products continue to be available across our Global Businesses. We have developed an initial framework for limiting the sale of IBOR based contracts.',
'Questions this paper addresses',
'1)\tWhat frameworks have our Global Businesses put in place to limit the sale of IBOR based contracts? And what is their implementation status?',
'2)\tWhat does the decision making process look like? And what decisions have been made to date?  ',
'3)\tWhat is the implementation status? ',
'Conclusions',
'1)\tOur Global Businesses have designed frameworks and associated assurance models that will govern the framework.',
'2)\tDecisions are approved by respective heads of business. To date GM have withdrawn two products only.',
'3)\tThe frameworks have been implemented and are live across all regions. The assurance model/approach has been implemented.',
'',
'Input Sought',
'This paper is for noting.',
'Input Received',
'IBOR Transition Programme Lead, IBOR CRO and IBOR Business leads',

Comment: why is it tagged machine learning, nlp, data-science/

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi because there might be few packages in them that could help me with my issue.

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning`, `nlp'` or `data-science` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed). The rationale you report is not what the tags are used for here.

Comment: @desertnaut But it can some packages like spacy, NLTK from NLP that could definitely help. why is my question closed?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I wrote. My algorithm works only if your docx still has the same format (Questions: \n 1) ... \n 2)... \n ... \n Conclusions: 1)... \n 2)...\n ...). For example if you put conclusions before questions it would not work.

I tried with the docx you provided and it works.

```
from docx2python import docx2python
import re

re_bullet = re.compile("[0-9]+\)") # integer followed by a parenthesis pattern

text = docx2python('test.docx').text #Docx to analyze



"""
    Count the number of questions contained into the text.
    Args : 
        text (str) : text to analyze 
    Returns :
        (int) : number of questions 
"""
def count_questions(text):
    result = 0
    lines= text.split("\n") #we split each lines
    for line in lines:
        if(line == "Conclusions:"): #if line contains "Conclusions:" then we stop to count questions.
            break

        if(re_bullet.match(line)): #if the line contains the bullet pattern then increment the result
            result+=1
    return result


"""
    Count the number of conclusions contained into the text.
    Args : 
        text (str) : text to analyze 
    Returns :
        (int) : number of conclusions 
"""
def count_conclusions(text):
    result = 0
    lines= text.split("\n")
    start_conclusion = False  #boolean to check if we are in the part which contains conclusions 
    for line in lines:
        if(line == "Conclusions:"):  #if line contains "Conclusions:" then we can start to count conclusions.
            start_conclusion = True

        if(re_bullet.match(line) and start_conclusion):
            result+=1
    return result


"""
    Check if there are as many questions as there are conclusions.
    Args : 
        text (str) : text to analyze 
    Returns :
        (boolean) : true if there are as many questions as there are conclusions, false if not.
"""
def questions_number_equals_to_conclusions_number(text):
    return count_questions(text) == count_conclusions(text)


print(str(questions_number_equals_to_conclusions_number(text)))
```

Here is the result :

> True

Comment: I've made minor changes, could you please go through them and modify. Can this be done by using spacy?!

Comment: I have already wrote the entire code. Normally, I should'nt do it so please try to do it by yourself and if you got any troubles, share your problems here, I will be glad to help you ! (And the answer is yes, this is possible to use spacy)  :)

Comment: I've made some changes according to my actual document but its not working. it always shows false

Comment: Show me the content of your file.

Comment: I've edited it with sample content of my file. The sentences are actually in the next line in my output but after copying it here, it looks like in the same line. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion, I've tweaked it and it is working fine. There is thia last thing I'm wondering if it's possible and it is asked in this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64610705/how-to-check-if-detailed-info-for-a-question-is-provided-or-not-in-a-word-docume"

Comment: @kaushik, please accept my answer to close the topic