# How to check if detailed info for a question is provided or not in a word document?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, nltk, spacy

I have few questions and elaborated context related to those questions in a .DOCX document. I need to find out if they have provided extra info for that respective question.

For instance:

(some text paragraphs)

Questions:

1. Question1?
2. Question2? Another question?
3. Question3?

(some text paragraphs)

1. Question1? (These questions will be the exact same as question1 mentioned above)

   Detailed info with regards to this question.
2. Question2? Another question?

   Detailed info with regards to this question.
3. Question3?

   Detailed info with regards to this question.

I have to check if extra info has been provided with respect to the same question in that document. Each document might have different set of questions, all I need to do is to identify each of the questions and check if there are these same questions (no need to check for the answer part)are mentioned over later in the document
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the question pattern, you just need to check if between 2 questions there is an answer.

Comment: Each document might have different set of questions, all I need to do is to identify each of the questions and check if there are these same questions (no need to check for the answer part)are mentioned over later in the document.

Comment: If you have many Word documents and you want to check if there are repetitions in your documents, then you have to read each question and then you can add each question to an array. If the question is already in the array then you have found a repetition. More over, if you want to localize repetitions, I advise you to use a dictionary with the question as key and an array of string which contains each filename in which the question appears. Hope it helps :)